# Camera's exposure in OpenCV/Python in different operating system

Tags: python, opencv, exposure

I was working my project with one webcam in both windows10 and ubuntu 16.04, and I find when I get this webcam's exposure by `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)`, I will get a negative integer (around -5 to -7) in windows10, and a positive integer (around 70) in ubuntu 16.04, I want to know why there is difference? and what is the meaning of value of cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE in windows10 and ubuntu 16.04 is respectively?

In both operating system, I have my python environment as follow:

> python=3.5.4
> opencv-python=4.1.0.25

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the difference could be that that the flag cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE is not supported in that OS.  so use the camera API to control instead.

Comment: Does it change your camera exposure? Cos its not supported with many cameras. [Here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/96137/is-there-any-range-of-values-for-the-exposure-flag/) also mentioned about it.

Comment: @Ziri I think the flag cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE is supported in both operating system, but I will try use the camera API to control. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk It can indeed change the camera's exposure in both operating system. The link helps a lot, thanks!